# Cell Reference Modification

Tags: vba, excel

I have selected a range of cells and I would like to concatenate the cell references of the cells selected with the word SUM.

e.g. If I select cell A1 I want my macro to return a reference "A1SUM"

**My code**

```
Sub UpdateCellReference()
    For Each mycell In Selection
        mycell.Name (mycell.Name & "SUM")
    Next mycell
End Sub
```

Comment: So if you select range A1:A7 you want it called `A1SUMA2SUMA3SUMA4SUMA5SUMA6SUMA7SUM`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. Thanks

Comment: `strName= strName & Replace(mycell.Address,"$","") & "SUM"` and then `mycell.Name (strName)`

Comment: I got the error Run-time error '438', Object doesn't support this property  or method

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
Sub UpdateCellReference()

    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim MyStr   As String

    For Each mycell In Selection
        MyStr = MyStr & mycell.Address(False, False) & "SUM"
    Next mycell

    MsgBox MyStr
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your input,I ran the code but it just returned A1SUM in the MSG box but it didn't actually alter the cell reference

Answer (score 0):

Using Shai Rado's code as a starting point.

Change his `MsgBox MyStr` line to

```
AllocateNamedRange ThisWorkbook, MyStr, "='" & Selection.Parent.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address, "A1"
```

and add these two procedures to the module:

```
Public Sub AllocateNamedRange(Book As Workbook, sName As String, sRefersTo As String, Optional ReferType = "R1C1")
    With Book
        If NamedRangeExists(Book, sName) Then .Names(sName).Delete
            If ReferType = "R1C1" Then
                .Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:=sRefersTo
        ElseIf ReferType = "A1" Then
                .Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersTo:=sRefersTo
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function NamedRangeExists(Book As Workbook, sName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
        NamedRangeExists = Book.Names(sName).Index <> (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```